# How to set Member List Api Youtube by GAS

Tags: google-apps-script, youtube-api

'm trying to get the subscribing members, through the Youtube page, but I'm getting as a response:

> GoogleJsonResponseException: API call to youtube.members.list failed
> with error: Access forbidden. The request may not be properly
> authorized.

Add multiples scopes in appscript.json ("https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube.channel-memberships.creator", "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube.readonly", "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets", "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube",

the code initial is this:

> const getPublicSubiscribers = () => {  let result =
> YouTube.Members.list("snippet", {"mode": 'all_current', "maxResults":
> 50 }); let nextPageToken = result.nextPageToken; const subs =
> [...result.items];
>
> Logger.lo(result)}

could someone help me please?